# How can I use regular expressions to find a word and copy it to a specific location?

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext3, nsregularexpression

Can you please tell me how I can use regular expressions to find what is written between the tags, copy it and paste it between the tags?
I've been racking my brains for an hour, I can't find the formula))

Example:

```
<category id="1"><name>Мужские куртки</name><short></short></category>
<category id="2"><name>Мужские брюки</name><short></short></category>
<category id="3"><name>Мужские портянки</name><short></short></category>
```

Need to:

```
<category id="1"><name>Мужские куртки</name><short>Мужские куртки</short></category>
<category id="2"><name>Мужские брюки</name><short>Мужские брюки</short></category>
<category id="3"><name>Мужские портянки</name><short>Мужские портянки</short></category>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    <category id="(\d+)"><name>(.*?)</name><short></short></category>
Replace: <category id="$1"><name>$2</name><short>$2</short></category>
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<category id="\d+"><name>(.*?)</name><short>\K(?=</short></category>)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<category id="\d+"><name>       # literally
(.*?)                           # group 1, 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
</name><short>                  # literally
\K                              # forget all we have seen until this position
(?=</short></category>)         positive lookbehind, zero length assertion that makes sure we have lose tags after
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, the text
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]